# Why is one Method being stuffed into another? C#

Tags: c#, methods

If any of you have been following my slow learning process, you'll know what's going on.

I created a border rectangle that looks like this:

```
+--------+
|        |
|        |
|        |
+--------+
Are you ready to play hangman? yes/no:
```

Granted, it's bigger and more rectangular.

Unfortunately, with the code I have now, what used to have the words below the rectangle, now have them in the middle, like this:

```
+--------+
|abcdefghi...        |
Are you ready . . . 
|        |
|        |
+--------+
```

Now, the box is big enough to fit all the words into it, but the initiating question should be below the field. It all started when I called the alphabet into an array, then had it display at specific coordinates.

Here is my code:

```
namespace Hangman
{
    class Program
    {

        protected static int firstColumn;
        protected static int firstRow;


        protected static void headerWindow(string border, int posX, int posY)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(firstColumn + posX, firstRow + posY);
                Console.Write(border);

            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException error)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write(error.Message);

            }

        }


        private static void printWord()
        {
            String[] myWordArrays = File.ReadAllLines("WordList.txt");
            Random randomWord = new Random();
            //int lineCount = File.ReadLines("WordList.txt").Count();            
            int activeWord = randomWord.Next(0, myWordArrays.Length);
            string userSelection = "";

            Console.WriteLine("Are you Ready to play Hangman? yes/no: ");

            userSelection = Console.ReadLine();
            if (userSelection == "yes")
            {

                foreach (char letter in myWordArrays[activeWord])
                {
                    Console.Write("_ ");

                }


                Console.WriteLine("\n \nCan you guess what this " + myWordArrays[activeWord].Length + " letter word is?");

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (userSelection == "no")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry you feel that way. Press Enter to Exit the program!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }

        //THIS IS THE CREATION OF THE RECTANGLE!!!
        private static void headerFile()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            firstColumn = Console.CursorLeft;
            firstRow = Console.CursorTop;

            int HEADER_HEIGHT = 6;
            int columnNumber = Console.WindowWidth - 1;
            var xcoord = 0;
            var ycoord = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < columnNumber; i++)
            {
                headerWindow("-", i, 0);
                headerWindow("-", i, HEADER_HEIGHT);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < HEADER_HEIGHT; i++)
            {
                headerWindow("|", 0, i);
                headerWindow("|", columnNumber, i);

            }
            headerWindow("+", xcoord = 0, ycoord = 0);
            headerWindow("+", xcoord = columnNumber, ycoord = 0);
            headerWindow("+", xcoord = 0, ycoord = 6);
            headerWindow("+", xcoord = columnNumber, ycoord = 6);



        }

        //THIS IS THE CREATION OF THE LIST OF UNUSED CHARACTERS FOR THE GAME
        private static void letterChoices()
        {
            string[] alphabetSelection = File.ReadAllLines("alphabet.txt");

            for (int i = 0; i < alphabetSelection.Length; i++)
            {
                headerWindow(alphabetSelection[i] + " ", i + 1, 1);
                Console.WriteLine("\n ");


            }
            //return;


        }


        //SHOULD I HAVE MORE HERE??
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            headerFile();
            letterChoices();
            printWord();


        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate not being given the answer as I really need to figure it out for myself, but I've moved the method call from main to headerwindow(), and I've even written it all out separately and in different ways. Ugh!

Please help!

Comment: Is everything supposed to be under the box? Or just the question 'Are you ready..?'. It's not too clear from your description

Comment: The letters are to go inside the box, and should be spaced (I tried that and it didn't work either). The question, and any other userinput or console 'output' (other than striking through used chars) should be below the box.

Comment: Got it! Also, about the spacing. You might want to try `i*2+1` instead of `i + 1` in your `letterChoices` method

Comment: @Rob - interesting. Might I ask why the i*2+1?

Comment: The second argument `i+1` is the column position to write to. Since you write one character each time, the width will also be one. Since your loop increments `i` by 1 each time, characters will be printed right next to each other. Changing `i+1` gives you the columns: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, etc - instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc. This will give you 1 space between each letter. If you'd like two spaces, you'd write: `i*3+1`

Comment: @Rob AHHHH. So THAT'S why the darned chars kept placing themselves right beside each other. LOL. You're awesome, Rob. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you asked not for a direct answer: The fix belongs in the method `headerWindow`. The same fix could also be applied in `letterChoices`, depending on your preference.

When the method `headFile()` finishes, the cursor is blinking at the bottom left of the box (in the 'correct' position to write text)

After your loop in `letterChoices`, your cursor is just below the alphabet, because it asked `headerWindow` to write in a certain position.

Something should be changed in `headerWindow` so that it doesn't keep the cursor where it just wrote to. You have used every property/method needed to create this fix, so it's not some arcane fix or hidden method on `Console`.

Comment: AHHHH. That makes complete friggin' sense. I hadn't even thought of it like that. Thank you so much. It's funny though, I tried doing a Console.SetCursorPosition at the end of the newly created 'alphabet' method, but it kept telling me I couldn't do it the way I was doing it, so I just deleted it and forgot about it. I'm thinking that's how I'm going to fix this is to reset the cursor after the alphabet thing finishes? Am I close?

Comment: *I tried doing a Console.SetCursorPosition at the end of the newly created 'alphabet' method* - If you sort out the syntax errors you were receiving when you tried before, I'm sure this will give you the result you want :)

Comment: I'd like to thank everyone for answering, but I've chosen Rob's as the best answer because he gave a very vague response to put me in the right direction and to figure it out on my own. These responses are GREATLY appreciated, because it allows me to still try and work through the debugging crud on my own without having the answers handed to me. 

But I do appreciate everyone that has answered, so thank you so much, especially to you Rob!

Answer (score 3):

Well the rectangle is created with what looks to be absolute positioning, but the text is based on relative positioning (i.e. it will print wherever the cursor is)

You can either look at making sure the header creation leaves the cursor where you want it OR make the other two methods also absolute positioning.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. What I wanted the rectangular box to do is stay put and be a static "header" for the "game." Kinda' like what you might find in a MUD. I want all I/O to be done in the console area (underneath the static box). But it seems that the box is being treated just like any other kind of text. In what I've just said, is the box not created properly for that?

Comment: First thing to remember the Console is 'infinite' vertical space, so your going to need to move everything to absolute positioning.  You already know the bounds of your window `Console.WindowWidth` & `.WindowHeight`.  So you can plan your layout based on that. The following might be useful http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/08/understanding-c-text-mode-games.html

Comment: Omg, thank you SOOOO much for that reference. I have been looking for this type of thing for some time now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's all about positions ...

What you need is to create a method that prints text using absolute positioning and call it like `PrintText("Hello", 20, 15);`

Comment: Well, the question needs to go below it, the letters must be inside of it. Maybe I'm going about that the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the cursor before writing `"Are you Ready to play Hangman?"`.
You can use :

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(column, row);
```

Comment: Cheater!!! lol. Thank you so much. Funny, I just read someone else's comment about where the cursor was ending after finishing the header and alphabet method and I was planning to try and add this somewhere! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can set the cursor at (o, HeaderHeight+1) before writing the 'Are You..' Message in printWord() method.

Console.SetCursorPosition(0, hh + 1);

Answer (score 0):

So I have fixed it, and wanted to update this question with the completed code for anyone else that had this same issue:

```
private static void letterChoices()
    {
        string[] alphabetSelection = File.ReadAllLines("alphabet.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < alphabetSelection.Length; i++)
        {
            //headerWindow("|", 0, 3);

            headerWindow(alphabetSelection[i], i*3+1, 1);
            //Console.Write("\n ");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 7);

        }
```

It now works properly, without any 'extra' spaces between the "|" on the sides and it properly places the first 'question' underneath the header. :)